# Maybe I need to export paths but not sure

Tags: python, linux, link-checking

I'm trying to use the check-html flag with linkchecker. It gives an error that the tidy module is not installed. If I say tidy at a command line I can use it. I have MacPorts installed and have installed just about every option for libtidy or tidy that has to do with python. I'm thinking it has to do with a $PATH issue or something.

So if I am using python26 and I go into python and then say import tidy there are no errors and all is well. If I use python27 I get errors when I say import tidy. I'm assuming because I installed py26-utidylib py26-pytidylib. There were no py27s. I don't mind being in python26. So it appears if I am in python26 I should be able to run tidy.

But when I run linkchecker it says the tidy module is not installed. When I say which python it says my location is /opt/local/bin/python. Do I need to export the $PATH or $PYTHONPATH or something for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

if you have 2 python compilers running, be sure you use the right one with the "python"-command.
you can see the used interpreter-version if you access the interactive-console with "python".

and you're right, the py26-...-library is for the python2.6 version. if there is no precompiled version you can always compile the library from the source for the required python-version. or at least, you can try. 
but here you have to be sure to choose the right python-interpreter to execute the setup-process.
if you want the library for the 2.7-version you have to build it with 2.7-version.

you can also always check the used paths in which the current running python-interpreter is looking for modules, through the interactive python console:

```
python

>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

i assume you have the library installed for the wrong version, has import the wrong module ... or using it wrong :/.

maybe you could supply your code example!?

Comment: @Thomas_Sittig `linkchecker --check-html http://example.com > /Users/user/Desktop/example,txt` - that is the code I am using...I get get the following error WARNING MainThread warning: tidy module is not available; download from http://utidylib.berlios.de/